# Is there a XmlReader method similar to the XmlWriter.WriteRaw method?

Tags: c#, xml

XmlWriter.WriteRaw will preserve &apos; and not send an actual apostrophe. Is there a method to read in &apos; and keep it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode it properly. Let's take for example the following XML:

```
<root>&apos;</root>
```

The value of the `<root>` node is `'` no matter which XML parser you use to read this XML.

On the other hand if you have the following XML:

```
<root>&amp;apos;</root>
```

the value of the `<root>` node is `&apos;`.

So in both cases we have properly encoded XML so that when a standard compliant parser reads it, it is able to correctly retrieve the value.

So be very careful when using the `WriteRaw` method when generating the XML. Since it properly encode the argument it is now your responsibility to ensure that you are passing correct data to it.

Comment: Can't modify the source, and I don't wanna do any replacing of characters before parsing it or anything like that. Big xml files would see a serious performance hit.

Comment: If you can't modify the source I am afraid that your only chance is to do some string replacing. .NET uses standard compliant XML parsers and if the XML is not generated properly you are out of luck. I would suggest you informing the author of the code to fix it if you cannot modify the source.

Comment: So, that leads to the final answer of if I want to read in xml with the unescaped entity references, I'd have to create it myself. This was my belief before asking this question, and it is the answer I'm left with.